# how to remove hover property on multi check box filter in kendo ui

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

while hovering on multi check box its showing message like "ProductName Filter Column Settings[image: scrrenshot]"
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-multi-checkboxes. how to remove this message or how to edit this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly remove the title from the [filterable.messages.buttonTitle](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/filterable.messages#filterablemessagesbuttontitle) option. Check the following [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aMAFUmiD)

```
filterable: {
  messages:{
    buttonTitle:" "
  }
}
```